# webutil how to read word file into an oracle forms Data Block

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I apply procedure "application Client_OLE2.Obj_Type". Read word file and enter data into oracle forms Data Block.

**I created this form:**

[image]

This code did not enter data into block. Please suggest me if any wrong in this code

**Code:**

```
declare
 arg_list client_ole2.list_type; 
 document client_ole2.obj_type; 
 documents client_ole2.obj_type;
 application client_ole2.obj_type;
 wordvalue  VARCHAR2(100);
 j  integer:=1;
BEGIN 

IF ( :BLOCK2.FILE IS NOT NULL ) THEN
application := client_OLE2.CREATE_OBJ('WORD.APPLICATION');
Client_OLE2.set_property(application,'Visible','false');

arg_list := client_ole2.create_arglist; 
documents := client_ole2.invoke_obj (application, 'documents'); 
client_ole2.add_arg (arg_list, :BLOCK2.FILE); 
document := client_ole2.invoke_obj (documents, 'Open', arg_list); 
client_ole2.destroy_arglist (arg_list);

--Go to the first record
    go_block('WE_GROUP_HOF_K'); 
    first_record;

loop
            If :system.record_status <> 'NEW' then
             create_record;
            end if;

for k in 1..1 loop
            arg_list:= Client_OLE2.create_arglist;
            Client_OLE2.add_arg(arg_list, j);
            Client_OLE2.add_arg(arg_list, k);
            document:= Client_OLE2.get_obj_property(documents, '', arg_list);
            Client_OLE2.destroy_arglist(arg_list);
            wordvalue := Client_OLE2.get_char_property(document, 'Value');

            if k =1 then
        :we_group_hof_k.clientid:=wordvalue;
end if;
end loop; --for

        j:=j+1;
    end loop;


client_ole2.RELEASE_OBJ (documents); 
END IF;
exception 
when others then
message(SQLERRM);
message(SQLERRM);

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

To Load BLOB file to Oracle Forms Block, Simply do this :

```
declare
        v_file_path varchar2(2000);
 begin
    v_file_path :=Get_file_name(select_file=>True);
        if v_file_path is not null then 
        initialize_container('Block.Item',v_file_path );
    End if;
end;
```